# Posting a blog entry with RealStudio (REALbasic)

Tags: rss, blogs, realbasic

I want to write a utility in RealStudio that will post a blog entry to a blog server... If that makes sense.

Has anyone done this before and is willing to give an example of what they did?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to know the API that is used to post to the server.  Check out [HTTPSocket](http://docs.realsoftware.com/index.php/HTTPSocket) and the Post method for one way to communicate with web servers.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. Thanks very much for your help

Answer (score 2):

As the oldest answer says, you will need to know the API the server uses (for the blog).  Then you will need to read/write to the API using the HTTPSocket.

Is there a reason you are writing a new application to post to a blog? There are many tools out there.